# Is there a Delphi equivalent to Java interfaces ("class ... implements")?

Tags: oop, delphi, interface

Assume I have two classes "*mycheckbox*" and "*mymemo*" derived from `TCheckBox` and `TMemo` respectively. I want to create a method for both entitled "*isdone*" which checks to see if the component has been completed. Is there a way of generically accessing that method without knowing which of the two classes one is dealing with?

In Java it would be: `class mycheckbox implements MyInterface`

Comment: Yes! You need to define [an interface](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Object_Interfaces_(Delphi)), maybe called `IControlStatus`, with a function `IsDone: Boolean`. Then you just have to make your new controls implement this interface.

Comment: Incredible that the feature even has the exact same name!

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The keyword [`interface` as unit section](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Programs_and_Units_(Delphi)#The_Interface_Section) might confuse non-Pascal people.

Comment: @AmigoJack There was no need to add "class ... implements" in the title. "interface" is a non-ambiguous concept in Java.

Comment: @Olivier While "interface" is the correct term it only helps those who already understand it. OP ignored punctuation (should have used quotes) to express himself in the terms he's used to - therefore I reverted the original while also leaving the correct term. Whoever searches the same way will find this Q more likely than if it would only hold correct (but to askers unknown) terms.

Comment: @AmigoJack Interface is universally known and recognizable term. There is no need for class implements in the title. I doubt that anyone coming from Java does not know what interface means. And for Delphi developers that don't know Java "class implements" would be completely unknown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Delphi, you would use a common interface, just like you would in Java, eg:

```pascal
type
  IMyInterface = interface
    ['{bfa4fffc-b87e-49ce-8aa9-4911e106959c}']
    function IsDone: Boolean;
  end;

  MyCheckBox = class(TCheckBox, IMyInterface)
  public
    function IsDone: Boolean;
  end;

  MyMemo = class(TMemo, IMyInterface) 
  public
    function IsDone: Boolean;
  end;

function MyCheckBox.IsDone: Boolean;
begin
 Result := ...;
end;

function MyMemo.IsDone: Boolean;
begin
 Result := ...;
end;

procedure DoSomething(Intf: IMyInterface);
begin
 ...
 if Intf.IsDone then...
 ...
end;
```